# Is this a bug or working as intended?

Tags: command-line, rar

```
find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e -o- {} /home/hilarie/Videos/season5 \;
```

Is the command I use to extract a directory containing several folders, containing multipart rar files.

when I try to substitute anything that isn't a `/home/hilarie/Videos/season5` into the command such as `~/Videos/season5` or if the folder `/home/hilarie/Videos/season5` hasn't been created yet, it errors out with this message

```
packed data checksum error in volume
```

Nothing is wrong with the volume, something is wrong with where it is trying to extract.  Is this a bug, or is it just me not being very good at copying and pasting from superuser.com?

The output of

```
echo $SHELL $0; type -a find unrar
```

is

```
/bin/bash /bin/bash
find is /usr/bin/find
unrar is /usr/bin/unrar
```

the output of
    find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar -o- {} /home/hilarie/Videos/season5 \;

which is the same except the e flag is

```
Cannot open /home/hilarie/Videos/season5.rar
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Assuming your `~` is `/home/hilarie`, substituting `~/Videos/season5` for `/home/hilarie/Videos` should work perfectly fine, if you're running this from a terminal. What's the output of `echo $SHELL $0; type -a find unrar`?

Comment: If you extract multipart volumes this command will unnecessarily try to extract every single part and then fail because the output files already exist. Maybe that's where the error comes from?

Comment: /bin/bash /bin/bash
find is /usr/bin/find
unrar is /usr/bin/unrar   @dessert Before doing it this way I check each directory for multiple files ending in .rar, this command is used for when it is 1 .rar and many .r1 .r2 and so on

Comment: @HilarieAK Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/957575/edit) and add this information to your question.

Comment: Would you kindly run the command as `find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar -o- {} /home/hilarie/Videos/season5 \;` and report the success. The use of unrar's e flag with an output path may be the cause of the error.

Comment: It will be several days before I can run that as I no longer have any multipart rar files to attempt extraction of, I can tell you with the absolute directory and if the folder exists, it does work with the e flag.

Comment: @J.Starnes It didn't work, edited in what happened

Answer (score 1):

Yes there does seem to be a bug between find and unrar. A quick workaround on my system is to wrap the `unrar` in a `bash -c` command.

```
find . -name "*.rar" -execdir bash -c 'unrar e -o- "{}" /home/hilarie/Videos/season5' \;
```

If the output dir is included in the unrar command, that directory must exist. A one liner such as this would work.

```
find . -name "*.rar" -execdir bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/hilarie/Videos/season5 && unrar e -o- "{}" /home/hilarie/Videos/season5' \;
```